# How do I get TeamCity to create the .git directory when building solution?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

The problem is, when I try to run the build, it errors saying " could not find .git directory". So I checked TeamCity's work directory on my agent  for my project, and there is no .git directory!

Why doesn't TeamCity create the .git directory? Is there a way to enable this?

Team city version : 8.0.6 
i am attaching snapshots of teamcity VCS settings.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you actually use TeamCity 8.0.6 which is 3+ years old now? Definitely worth upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

VCS checkout mode / "on agent" should do the trick. Provided you do have the VCS root attached (which seems on the screenshot like you do not).